# Audiokit - random crashes when app comes from background

Tags: ios, audio, audiokit

I've started experimenting with AudioKit - lovely framework, however I'm having some crashes that I can't trace.

To get started, I wanted to build a sequencer and I followed the example in this medium post: https://medium.com/@oleary.audio/building-a-midi-sequence-in-swift-bed5f5c2bb7d and also added some code to help visualise the current step played in the sequencer, using a callback instrument (as described here: [AudioKit ios AKSamplerMetronome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629637/audiokit-ios-aksamplermetronome/47630809#47630809)).

Everything is running fine when I am in the app, however if I exit and leave the app in the background and re-enter, it randomly (once every 4-5 tries) crashes with a stack trace that I don't understand (see below)
[image]

I'm not sure what might be causing this, or what might be calling the AKMIDIInstrument.enableMIDI function I'm seeing in the debugger. Any tips on this are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have to add that this only happens on a physical device, I haven't been able to reproduce it in the simulator.

EDIT2: I've also tried moving the callback instrument's callback function outside of the view controller and setting up a delegate to change the view, thinking that the view controller's lifecycle might affect it in some way, but the issue still persists.

Here's a simplified version of my code for reference:

```
class AudioCore {
    static let sharedInstance = AudioCore()
    let osc = AKOscillatorBank()
    let sequencer = AKSequencer()
    let callbackTrack:AKMusicTrack?
    let soundTrack:AKMusicTrack?
    let callbackInstrument = AKCallbackInstrument()
    let midi = AKMIDI()

    init() {
        let midiNode = AKMIDINode(node: osc)
        AudioKit.output = midiNode
        do {
            try AudioKit.start()
        }
        catch {
            AKLog("Audio kit failed to start")
        }

        if let track = sequencer.newTrack(){
            callbackTrack = track
            callbackTrack?.setMIDIOutput(callbackInstrument.midiIn)
        } else {
            callbackTrack = nil
        }

        if let sound = sequencer.newTrack(){
            soundTrack = sound
            soundTrack?.setMIDIOutput(midiNode.midiIn)
        } else {
            soundTrack = nil
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         for i in 0...10 {
            AudioCore.sharedInstance.soundTrack?.add(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber(pitch), velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: pos), duration: AKDuration(beats: dur))
            AudioCore.sharedInstance.callbackTrack?.add(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber(i), velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: pos), duration: AKDuration(beats: dur))
         }
         AudioCore.sharedInstance.callbackInstrument.callback = { status, note, vel in
             guard status == .noteOn else { return }
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if(note < self.buttons.count) {
                    self.buttons[note].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                 }
             }

             let dispatchDelay = 1.0 / tempo * 60.0 * noteLength
             DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + dispatchDelay, execute: {
                 if(note < self.buttons.count) {
                    self.buttons[note].backgroundColor = oldColor
                 }
             })
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: While I'm not having the same problem, I am having strange issues when transitioning my AK-based app from background. Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: I'm still having this crash fairly regularly, if not frequently, Did you ever find a reason or solution?