# What is the MIDIEndpointRef for the CallbackInstrument?

Tags: swift, audiokit

I would like to make runtime UI changes according to notes played by a sequencer.

Other solutions use a Callback Instrument and add another track with encoded values to the sequencer (f.e.: [AudioKit ios AKSamplerMetronome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629637/audiokit-ios-aksamplermetronome/47630809#47630809)).

However, the syntax appears to have changed, as running

`callbackTrack?.setMIDIOutput(callbackInst.midiIn)`

tells me that `AKCallbackInstrument` has no such member.

What is the updated syntax? Or is there a newer, better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The class formerly known as `AKCallbackInstrument` has been renamed to `AKMIDICallbackInstrument`.  The current `AKCallbackInstrument` is a different class.